# How to get language specific path in twig?

Tags: theming, 8, routes, i18n-l10n

In a twig template you are able to get a relative path by using `{{ path('entity.node.edit_form', {'node': nid }) }}`. The path will be in current language.

Now I need to get the path in a specfic language. I thought I could use `{{ path('entity.node.edit_form', {'node': nid }, {'language': langcode}) }}` but this results an error if I set `langcode` to a string like `DE`. According to the [api docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.2.x) `language` has to be a language object. How can I accomplish this in twig?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a twig only solution you can define a custom twig function `path_lang()`, which adds the language object to options, if a language code is  provided as additional parameter:

**src/TwigExtension.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule;

use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class TwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

  protected $languageManager;

  protected $urlGenerator;

  public function __construct(LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager, UrlGeneratorInterface $url_generator) {
    $this->languageManager = $language_manager;
    $this->urlGenerator = $url_generator;
  }

  public function getName() {
    return 'mymodule';
  }

  public function getFunctions() {
    return [
      new \Twig_SimpleFunction('path_lang', [$this, 'getPathLang']),
    ];
  }

  public function getPathLang($name, $parameters = [], $options = [], $langcode = '') {
    if (!empty($langcode)) {
      if ($language = $this->languageManager->getLanguage($langcode)) {
        $options['language'] = $language;
      }
    }
    return $this->urlGenerator->generateFromRoute($name, $parameters, $options);
  }
}
```

**mymodule.services.yml:**

```
services:
  mymodule.twig.extension:
    arguments: ['@language_manager', '@url_generator']
    class: Drupal\mymodule\TwigExtension
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

**In twig:**

```
{{  path_lang('entity.node.edit_form', {'node': nid }, {}, 'en') }}
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me into Twig extensions! It works like a charm and is reusable. Nevertheless I opened an feature request because I think this is a really common issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2813099

Comment: @4k4 Can you explain the difference between `parameters` and `options`? Im having trouble getting a query string in the link. The official [API doc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21UrlGenerator.php/function/UrlGenerator%3A%3AgenerateFromRoute/8.2.x) doesnt explain it very well.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work because I think that you need the language object and not only the langcode.

The best way to do this I think it's to do it in a THEME_preprocess_node in your yourtheme.theme file :

SOLUTION 1 (get translation of the node and then get the proper link) :

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    $node = &$vars['node'];
    // TO HAVE NODE URL IN ANY OF YOUR NODE TEMPLATES FOR CURRENT LANGUAGE
    $vars['node_url'] = $node->toUrl()->toString();
    // SOLUTION 1
    $node_de = $node->getTranslation('de');
    if ($node_de && is_object($node_de)) {
        $node_url = $node_de->toUrl()->toString();
        $vars['node_url_de'] = $node_url;
    }
}
```

SOLUTION 2 (get the url object of the node and then get translation of the url object) :

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    $node = &$vars['node'];
    // TO HAVE NODE URL IN ANY OF YOUR NODE TEMPLATES FOR CURRENT LANGUAGE
    $vars['node_url'] = $node->toUrl()->toString();
    // SOLUTION 2
    $language_manager = \Drupal::service('language_manager');
    $language_de = $language_manager->getLanguage('de');
    $urlNodeObject = $node->toUrl();
    $urlNodeObject->setOption('language', $language_de);
    // IF YOU WANT AN ABSOLUTE URL
    $urlNodeObject->setAbsolute();

    $vars['node_url_de'] = $urlNodeObject->toString();
}
```

Although I put `$vars['node_url'] = $node->toUrl()->toString();` to print `{{ node_url }}` instead of `{{ path('entity.node.edit_form', {'node': nid }) }}` because I think it's better.

Then in your TWIG template you just have to print `{{ node_url_de }}` for your aliased german node link.

Comment: I had hoped that there is an easy non-preprocess way, because this twig is used inside a user defined text field of a views view. I may open a feature request issue to allow a simple language code string instead of the language object. Otherwise it is really cumbersome to get a language specific path in twig.