# Getting a translated URL in a Node TWIG template

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, i18n-l10n

I was referring to this documentation, but am unsure if what I'm trying to do is possible: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates#path

In the section, it refers to this on building a URL:

```
{# Link to node page. #}
<a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}">{{ 'View node page'|t }}</a>
```

This returns a **TRULY** relative URL, in the sense that if I'm on an English node, the URL is translated to english.  If on a Spanish page, the URL is translated.  The thing is, I'm trying to create a link in the nodes to the OTHER language, so I need to be able to create unique links for each language in the opposing language's TWIG.

Anyone know of a way to get this URL in a language-dependant manner?

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45232856/295112

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, Kevin, but would the PHP code on that article require me to put it in a preprocess function, and print that out in the chosen twig template?  Or is there a way with TWIG to do a similar ting?  Sorry, I'm new to Drupal 8 theming.

Comment: Potentially... https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217009/how-to-get-language-specific-path-in-twig